# How can I replace the FOR loop by something faster

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, list-comprehension

I'm trying to transform my dataframe based on certain conditions. Following is my input dataframe

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
   DocumentNumber     I_Date     N_Date     P_Date  Amount
0            1234 2016-01-01 2017-01-01 2017-10-23   38.38
1            2345 2016-01-02 2017-01-02 2018-03-26   41.00
2            1324 2016-01-12 2017-01-03 2018-03-26   30.37
3            5421 2016-01-13 2017-01-02 2018-03-06  269.00
4            5532 2016-01-15 2017-01-04 2018-06-30  271.00
```

#### Desired solution:

- Each row is a unique document and my aim is to find the number of documents and their total amount, which meet the mentioned condition if I am running for each day and delta combination.
- I am able to get to my desired result via `for-loop`, but I know it is not the ideal way and gets slower as my data increases. Since I am new to python, I need help to get rid of the loop by a list comprehension or any other faster option.

#### Code:

```
d1 = datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)
d2 = datetime.date(2017, 1, 15)

mydates = pd.date_range(d1, d2).tolist()
Delta = pd.Series(range(0,5)).tolist()

df_A =[]


for i in mydates: 
    for j in Delta:
        A = df[(df["I_Date"]<i) & (df["N_Date"]>i+j) & (df["P_Date"]>i) ]
        A["DateCutoff"] = i
        A["Delta"]=j
        A = A.groupby(['DateCutoff','Delta'],as_index=False).agg({'Amount':'sum','DocumentNumber':'count'})
        A.columns = ['DateCutoff','Delta','A_PaymentAmount','A_DocumentNumber']
        df_A.append(A)

df_A = pd.concat(df_A, sort = False)
```

#### Output:

```
In [14]: df_A
Out[14]: 
  DateCutoff  Delta  A_PaymentAmount  A_DocumentNumber
0 2017-01-01      0           611.37                 4
0 2017-01-01      1           301.37                 2
0 2017-01-01      2           271.00                 1
0 2017-01-02      0           301.37                 2
0 2017-01-02      1           271.00                 1
0 2017-01-03      0           271.00                 1
```

Comment: Pandas supports element-wise operations, so that can be done easily. However, could you provide minimally reproducible code so we can assist you?

Comment: You should also explain in words what you are doing. Your code runs, but it is not readable and the logic behind the data manipulation not obvious at all.

Comment: Everything gets slower as your data increases

Comment: @NicolasGervais - Thanks for replying. I have edited the code. Does this help?

Comment: @Valentino - Thanks for replying. I updated the post with logic explanation. Let me know if it is still unclear to u.

Comment: As a general rule, yes there are better ways if you are using pandas. But it's hard to point out a valid alternative without understanding the task.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree but there are better options than FOR loop. Right?

Comment: `i+j`, Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays to Timestamp is deprecated

Comment: As already mentioned before, explain the logic of your code in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't see a way to remove the loop from your code, because the loop is creating individual dataframes based on the contents of `mydates` and `Delta`.

   - In this example you are creating 75 different dataframes
   - On each dataframe you `.groupby`, then `.agg` the `sum` of payments and the `count` of document numbers.
   - Each dataframe is appended to a list.
   - `pd.concat` the complete list into a dataframe.
2. **One significant improvement**

   - Check the Boolean condition before creating the dataframe and performing the remaining operations.  In this example, operations were performed on 69 empty dataframes.  By checking the condition first, operations will only be performed on the 6 dataframes containing data.
   - `condition.any()` returns `True` as long as at least one element is `True`
3. Minor changes

   - `datetime` + `int` is deprecated, so change that to `datetime` + `timedelta(days=x)`
   - `pd.Series(range(0,5)).tolist()` is overkill for making a list.  Now `timedelta` objects are needed, so use `[timedelta(days=x) for x in range(5)]`
   - Instead of iterating with two `for-loops`, use `itertools.product` on `mydates` and `Delta`.  This creates a generator of tuples in the form `(Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00', freq='D'), datetime.timedelta(0))`
   - Use `.copy()` when creating dataframe `A`, to prevent `SettingWithCopyWarning`
4. Note:

   - A `list comprehension` was mentioned in the question.  They are just a `pythonic` way of making a `for-loop`, but don't necessarily improve performance.
   - All of the calculations are using pandas methods, not `for-loops`.  The `for-loop` only creates the dataframe from the condition.

### Updated Code:

```py
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2017, 1, 1)
d2 = date(2017, 1, 15)

mydates = pd.date_range(d1, d2)
Delta = [timedelta(days=x) for x in range(5)]

df_list = list()

for t in product(mydates, Delta):
    condition = (df["I_Date"]<t[0]) & (df["N_Date"]>t[0]+t[1]) & (df["P_Date"]>t[0])
    if condition.any():
        A = df[condition].copy()
        A["DateCutoff"] = t[0]
        A["Delta"] = t[1]
        A = A.groupby(['DateCutoff','Delta'],as_index=False).agg({'Amount':'sum','DocumentNumber':'count'})
        A.columns = ['DateCutoff','Delta','A_PaymentAmount','A_DocumentNumber']
        df_list.append(A)

df_CutOff = pd.concat(df_list, sort = False)
```

#### Output

- The same as the original

```py
  DateCutoff  Delta  A_PaymentAmount  A_DocumentNumber
0 2017-01-01      0           611.37                 4
0 2017-01-01      1           301.37                 2
0 2017-01-01      2           271.00                 1
0 2017-01-02      0           301.37                 2
0 2017-01-02      1           271.00                 1
0 2017-01-03      0           271.00                 1
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the well explained answer. It really served the purpose. I ran the logic on a bigger dataset and it reduced the processing time from 30 to 6mints.

Comment: That's great, glad to help.

Comment: Do you think converting into a numy array before the groupby logic will further enhance the performance speed?

Comment: I don't really see how.  The only line that's doing a calculation is `A = A.groupby(['DateCutoff','Delta'],as_index=False).agg({'Amount':'sum','DocumentNumber':'count'})`.  I don't know know that putting it in a numpy array will make a difference.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Its taking 45mints to run on another dataset which got me thinking what else I can change.

Comment: `condition = (df["I_Date"]<t[0]) & (df["N_Date"]>t[0]+t[1]) & (df["P_Date"]>t[0])` is probably time consuming, but I don't have a suggesting to for improving that step.

Comment: Can we do this filtering outside of the loop? Like a KD tree thing?